# Turning Repeated JQuery into reusable function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm New to JQuery...

I am Toggling a DIV every time a button is clicked... previously I would create a new set of jquery code each time that I would add another DIV (product). This site will be using a content management system so I need to turn this repeated code into a function...

The code that I am repeating to toggle the DIV when the ID is clicked.

```
        // Product Detail Toggle Buttons
        $("#xc25_button").click(function(e){ 
            $("#xc25_detail").find(".product_details").slideToggle("slow");
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });

        $("#xc27_button").click(function(e){ 
            $("#xc27_detail").find(".product_details").slideToggle("slow");
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
```

I tried to write a function and pass in the "specific name" with the following:

```
        // Products Detail Toggle Function
        var productDetail = function(productId){
            $("#" + productId + "_button").click(function(e){ 
                $("#" + productId + "_detail").find(".product_details").slideToggle("slow");
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }); 
        }
```

Two Problems --

1. Whats wrong with the code
2. How do I activate the productDetail("value") for each instance in the HTML

HTML Following:

```
        <a href="#"><span id="xc25_button">More Details</span></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="xc25_detail">
                    <div class="product_details">
                    <p>Some Text</p>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks for your help all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to add classes to your elements. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><span id="xc25_button" >More Details</span></a>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="xc25_detail" class="details">
    <div class="product_details">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can bind using the class selector and combine that with `this` to select the related element:

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    $(this).nextAll(".details:eq(0)").find(".product_details").slideToggle("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`this` will be the specific button that triggered the event handler and from there we use DOM traversal methods to navigate to the next sibling element with the `details` class and from there down to the child with the `product_details` class and toggle it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LfuWq/

Comment: Hey Matt - Thanks for the quick reply, I hope I have not implemented incorrectly, however i can't seem to get that code to work -- broke it out onto it's own page as well, still not working. Can you double check just to make sure I am not spinning my wheels for nothing?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I missed that the handler was on the span instead of the parent `<a>`. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you sir -- that was it ... for my personal knowledge eq(1) should select the next instance of details shouldn't it? Not that it matters for this example by why wouldn't it grab that? Also, in removing eq(0), this code still works... reason to include it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
$.fn.extend({ 

myFunction:function(){

    var $this=$(this); // WHATEVER CALLS THIS FUNCTION
}

});
```

Then just call it:

```
$('#el').myFunction();
```